# Avoiding Concurrency - DGV Error in the First Place

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, concurrency, datagridview

I get the feeling that I am not using the table adapters the way I'm supposed to.  I've read several questions here and [this MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4) on handling concurrency errors in datagridview's (DGV).

In my setup, I will only have one user accessing the table at a time, and it's going to be on the local HD where the person is working.  I use multiple DGV on multiple tabs in a tabcontrol.  The DGV are binding to a table in an Access DB.  When a user tries to enter values on multiple cells across two or more rows, they will run into a concurrency error after the second cell on the second row.  After handling the concurrency error, once, and refilling the DGV, which updates the primary key column, they won't have any errors.

Going back to existing values in the DGV also doesn't cause errors, it seems to only happen if the key column (which the users don't enter but can sort by) `Is DBNull`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Dim m_DtChemical As New DataTable
Dim ChemicalAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim m_Bsource As New BindingSource

Sub FillChemicalDataGrid()
    ChemicalAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Chemicals", ConMain)
    m_DtChemical.Clear()
    ChemicalAdapter.Fill(m_DtChemical)
    m_Bsource.DataSource = m_DtChemical
    ChemicalDataGridView.DataSource = m_Bsource
End Sub


Sub UpdateChemicalsDatabase()
    Try
        Dim ObjComander As New OleDbCommandBuilder(ChemicalAdapter)
        ChemicalAdapter.Update(m_DtChemical)

    Catch ex2 As DBConcurrencyException
        OhGodImStuckErrorHandler()
        MsgBox("Concurrency Error.  Reloading Table.")
        FillChemicalDataGrid()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an error updating to the database. " & ex.Message)
        WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.GetHashCode, ex.Source, ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ChemicalDataGridView_RowValidated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles ChemicalDataGridView.RowValidated 'tried CellLeave, CellEnter, CellValidated...etc
    Call UpdateChemicalsDatabase()
End Sub
```

I've tried to cause the merge and the update to happen, especially `If IsDBNull(DGV(0, Xrow).Value) = true`

Am I way off in what I'm trying to do?  It seems to be only from instances where the ID (primary key column) is in fact DBNull.  Is there a better way I should be handling this?  Rather than handling the concurrency error, I feel like I should be able to avoid it in the first place if I could just figure out how.

I have similar projects in VB.net and C#, both with the exact same problem.  I'm slightly more comfortable in VB.Net, but I'd be happy with answer in ether.

EDIT: Describing the scenario in response to comments:

So a user would come in and fill in a cell on new row in the DGV (name for instance).  If they only fill the one row out, then everything updates/inserts correctly, the DB assigns an ID to it, and it shows back up next time it's accessed.  If they try to write in more than one column per new row it throws a concurrency error.  I note that as they add each new row, the DGV has the ID as DBNull, but when it is refreshed or filled it will use the ID generated by the DB.  It never runs into a concurrency error when the DGV is showing the correct key in the ID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your "Key column" allows for DBNull.  You must have a primary key column for MS to be able to merge records and prevent you from having the same record multiple times.

What is happening here is that you have the same record in your cache multiple times and when you update the one record, the other record is out of sync.  By using a single dataset and applying primary keys to each datatable, you eliminate multiple copied of data. When you do something like a DataAdapter.Fill(), MS will MERGE the data, not just blindly add the same records again.  Then when you save, it will update and reset flags on the record so the next time you save, you dont run into concurrancy errors.

Comment: I think I'm following here, but I haven't figured out how to designate in the DGV.  The access DB doesn't allow DBNull for the ID, instead it's the primary key and auto-incremented.  I assume there's a way to set the data table primary key (if there was an obvious way to do it through the designer I didn't see it)?

Comment: I dont use the designer but it should pickup the PK from the table in access.  Question is, what did you mean by "it seems to only happen if the key column Is DBNull" when you now say "The access DB doesn't allow DBNull for the ID"?  Are you creating records, saving them to the DB, then trying to modify them again?

Comment: Just edited the question to address your questions.  Am I just not identifying the right time to update or refresh the DGV?  I'm not sure which event should handle sending data back to the DB.  My goal is to have a "live" like edit of the DB through the DGV.

Comment: You should not update the database with the change of every field in a record.  You can but this is frowned upon.  If you MUST, then your issue is still the same. You are creating a record that is then saved and MS Access assigns an ID (classic scenerio).  Now you must replace the old record (no PK) with the new record.

Comment: Question is, how do you do that, right? You should be able to remove the new record from binding source and datatable, then add the new one.

Comment: So then I would need to define separate commands for inserting, updating, and deleting?  I just want to make sure, I thought that was part of what the table adapter was doing for me?

Comment: No, you need to define those and because you have a special case (MS Access Identity), you may need to add some special code to your insert that will get you the ID of the newly created record. This way you can replace your existing record with the new one, from the DB. There are several post on SO that talk about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle concurrency problems is to determine dirty rows.

One way to check if something is dirty is during your query you should get the timestamp of the row (e.i. the row has a timestamp column and during an update this column is set to getdate())

Now before doing an actual update in your application, what you do is load first the timestamp of the row you are trying to update and if the timestamps you have for the row matches with the one in the DB, then you know dont have a dirty row and you can proceed with the update.

Now if you have a dirty row.. you have some things to think about how to handle it... like - maybe

1. update only rows that is not dirty
2. stop the whole update process and reload the rows that have been updated and notify the user that these rows have been updated.
3. or allow the user to actually overwrite the data of the other users without getting their changes.

Up to you depending on your requirements.

Comment: The problem is that using the system above, a single user using one instance of the application, is able to make a dirty row.  That's why I think I'm doing something wrong.  I can't seem to "referesh"/update at the right moment so that users don't loose a lot of input.

Comment: Dirty is only a concept that what you are saving you may have taken from an old state.  If you are trying to save many records at a time then it may pose an issue.  Better change your strategy of updating one record at a time (unless you have problems with consistency") bec multiple rows are part of an aggregate.  Have you tried "Domain Driven Design" to handle aggregate concurrency?  http://practical-ddd.blogspot.sg/